# Format used in INPUT section while importing a CSV file into SAS

Tags: csv, input, import, sas, format

I'd like to get a list of formats used for each variable in the INPUT section. For example, say, we have a csv file and manually import data into SAS. In the code section, we will have smth like that:

```
DATA WORK.SAS_data_1;
LENGTH
    A                  8
    B                $ 9
    C                  8
    D                  8
    E                  8 ;
FORMAT
    A                BEST1.
    B                $CHAR9.
    C                MMDDYY10.
    D                BEST1.
    E                BEST3. ;
INFORMAT
    A                BEST1.
    B                $CHAR9.
    C                MMDDYY10.
    D                BEST1.
    E                BEST3. ;
INFILE 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\SEG3592\SAS_data_1-ab6243ce7f064047b5e010c113d2f6a3.txt'
    LRECL=27
    ENCODING="WLATIN1"
    TERMSTR=CRLF
    DLM='7F'x
    MISSOVER
    DSD ;
INPUT
    A                : ?? BEST1.
    B                : $CHAR9.
    C                : ?? MMDDYY9.
    D                : ?? BEST1.
    E                : ?? BEST3. ;
RUN;
```

I'd like to know what formats are used in the INPUT section, that is: BEST1. for A, $CHAR9. for B, MMDDYY9. for C, etc.

I've found the code that summaries the format and informat for each variable in SASHELP.CARS dataset but I cannot find the format used in the INPUT section. Does anyone know where to find it? At times (for numerical variables) these formats can be different. Here is the code:

```
proc sql noprint ;
create table varlist as
select memname,varnum,name,type,length,format,informat, label
from dictionary.columns
where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CARS'
;
quit;
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Ken. I'm sorry, I never wanted to create such an impression. I probably had my caps lock key on while typing this question. So sorry.

Comment: No problem.  Thank you for being polite. :-)

Comment: Do you have examples of "formats [that] can be different" from what you get with the dictionary query? (I'm guessing the differences occur when `BEST.` is used at the import stage?)

Comment: `format` and `informat` are different - you almost certainly mean `informat` (the bit in the input code would be an informat).

Comment: Yes, I've just found that in the INPUT section we use INFORMAT. Thank you very much, Joe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to recover the original input code used for a particular dataset.  If informats were used with the `INFORMAT` statement, then you can see those (as you did in your example).

But determining whether a dataset was read in like this:

```
data have;
  input x;
  datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
;;;;
run;
```

Or like this:

```
data have;
  input @1 x 1.;
datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
;;;;
run;
```

Or even this:

```
data have;
  input @1 x 12.;
datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
;;;;
run;
```

All would appear exactly identically in SAS and have exactly identical metadata.  The only way to know how they were input would be to have access to the input program and log it.

Comment: Thank you, Joe. I appreciate your explanation. It's much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

SAS does not need be told how to convert most strings into values. In your example only the variable `C` needs to use special informat so that SAS knows how to interpret the text as a date.

You can use the INFORMAT statement to attach an informat specification to a variable in a dataset. However that metadata does not really serve much purpose in SAS, except perhaps if you are still using PROC FSEDIT.

If you want to store instructions on how your text file (CSV files are text files) is formatted then you should store that information into another document (or database). Or just save the SAS program.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. If I understand it correctly, I can only apply INFORMAT but I cannot distinguish between, say, comma8. from best8. for a numerical value, correct?

Comment: The normal numeric informat, *w.* (which is what you get if you use to alias `best.` as an informat), does not understand what to do with the commas. So if your source text has embedded commas and/or dollar signs then you will need to use an informat (or read it as character).  Use the `comma.` (also known as `dollar.`) informat to read that type of data. Basically it just strips out the commas and dollar sings and then reads the result like a normal number.

Comment: Once the data is in a SAS variable you use **formats** to tell SAS how to display the values.  Whether you display the value with or without commas the value stored is the same.  SAS only has two data types, floating point numbers and fixed length character strings.